# How to groupBy/Tag into same group under conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below. This dataframe contains name and address information.

```
l_name   f_name   m_name    city_state     zip 
smith     sam                auburn,wa    98910
smith     sam       c        auburn,wa    98910
smith     sam                durham,nc    27659
smith     sam     eddie      auburn,wa    98910
smith     sam                auburn,wa    98910
  :
  :
aaron     joe     chris      ocala,fl     58910
aaron     joe                ocala,fl     58910
aaron     joe                durham,nc    27659
aaron     joe                ocala,fl     58910
aaron     joe       a        ocala,fl     58910
```

I am trying to create a code that can group/tag them into the same group if their l_name, f_name, city_state, and zip columns all match.

Here is what the output dataframe I am hoping to look like.

```
l_name   f_name   m_name    city_state     zip       tag
smith     sam                auburn,wa    98910       1
smith     sam       c        auburn,wa    98910       1
smith     sam                durham,nc    27659       0
smith     sam     eddie      auburn,wa    98910       1
smith     sam                auburn,wa    98910       1
clair     may                seattle,wa   98092       2
clair     may       a        seattle,wa   98092       2
clair     may                seattle,wa   98092       2
  :
  :
aaron     joe     chris      ocala,fl     58910       n
aaron     joe                ocala,fl     58910       n
aaron     joe                durham,nc    27659       0
aaron     joe                ocala,fl     58910       n
aaron     joe       a        ocala,fl     58910       n
```

If the person doesn't belong to any group, it will assign a 0 to it. 4 sam smith meets the conditions so they are all in the same group, which is 1. So tag/group 2 will be may clair, and joe aaron will be the n group, depending on how many names were stored in the dataframe.

I am wondering are there any good ways, methods, or suggestions for me to create a code that can output the results that I want above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take those groups with > 1 count and get the group number (and +1 ), then for groups of count 1, set tag = 0. Then concatenate.

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(['l_name', 'f_name', 'city_state', 'zip'])['m_name'].transform('count')>1].copy()
df1['tag'] = df1.groupby(['l_name', 'f_name', 'city_state', 'zip']).ngroup() + 1

df2 = df[df.groupby(['l_name', 'f_name', 'city_state', 'zip'])['m_name'].transform('count')==1].copy()
df2['tag'] = 0

df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_final

  l_name f_name m_name city_state    zip  tag
0  smith    sam      x  auburn,wa  98910    2
1  smith    sam      c  auburn,wa  98910    2
3  smith    sam  eddie  auburn,wa  98910    2
4  smith    sam      x  auburn,wa  98910    2
5  aaron    joe  chris   ocala,fl  58910    1
6  aaron    joe      x   ocala,fl  58910    1
8  aaron    joe      x   ocala,fl  58910    1
9  aaron    joe      a   ocala,fl  58910    1
2  smith    sam      x  durham,nc  27659    0
7  aaron    joe      x  durham,nc  27659    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still learning Python, what does ngroup do compare to groupby

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it works for you. groupby and ngroup work together. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html

Comment: Your code works but for some reason, it deducts my dataframe in half. I tried your code on my dataframe (371 rows) but the final dataframe only has 164 rows. I am still trying to figure out why.

Comment: I put x in m_name. It’s possible when that is blank it’s removing rows??? You may have to use another column to count on as a step toward debugging

Comment: That makes sense. I am going to try to run the code again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `ngroup` and count its values afterwards:

```
# create a ID variable with a unique identifier for each group
groupvar = df.groupby(['l_name', 'f_name', 'city_state', 'zip']).ngroup(ascending=False) + 1
# assign it to the data 
df = df.assign(tag=groupvar)
df
    l_name  f_name  m_name  city_state  zip     tag
0   smith   sam             auburn,wa   98910   2
1   smith   sam     c       auburn,wa   98910   2
2   smith   sam             durham,nc   27659   1
3   smith   sam     eddie   auburn,wa   98910   2
4   smith   sam             auburn,wa   98910   2
5   clair   may             seattle,wa  98092   3
6   clair   may     a       seattle,wa  98092   3
7   clair   may             seattle,wa  98092   3
8   aaron   joe     chris   ocala,fl    58910   4
9   aaron   joe             ocala,fl    58910   4
10  aaron   joe             durham,nc   27659   5
11  aaron   joe             ocala,fl    58910   4
12  aaron   joe     a       ocala,fl    58910   4

# determine which IDs occur only once and assign 0 to them
df.loc[df['tag'].value_counts()[df['tag']].values == 1, 'tag'] = 0
df
    l_name  f_name  m_name  city_state  zip     tag
0   smith   sam             auburn,wa   98910   2
1   smith   sam     c       auburn,wa   98910   2
2   smith   sam             durham,nc   27659   0
3   smith   sam     eddie   auburn,wa   98910   2
4   smith   sam             auburn,wa   98910   2
5   clair   may             seattle,wa  98092   3
6   clair   may     a       seattle,wa  98092   3
7   clair   may             seattle,wa  98092   3
8   aaron   joe     chris   ocala,fl    58910   4
9   aaron   joe             ocala,fl    58910   4
10  aaron   joe             durham,nc   27659   0
11  aaron   joe             ocala,fl    58910   4
12  aaron   joe     a       ocala,fl    58910   4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a try. Also, I am wondering does it work if the names are in random order, for example, row 1 is sam smith, but then row 23 is sam smith, and row 49 is sam smith

Comment: I tried your code but the output tag column didnt is kinda weird. It will start from 0, 1,2 then jump to 5, etc. That means it skips 3 and 4. I am trying figure out why

Comment: hey, I updated my answer to shed more light into each step. Hope this makes it easier to follow. The downside here is indeed that groupID is not strongly sequential but this should not impede most subsequent steps. Leave me a note otherwise. Cheers